# setInterval is not refresh data every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

```js
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay()
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear()
var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

function dateTimeClock() {
  $('#today').text(today);
  $('#day').text(day);
  $('#month').text(month);
  $('#year').text(year);
  $('#date').text(date);
  $('#time').text(time);
  $('#dateTime').text(dateTime);
}

setInterval(dateTimeClock, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="today"></p>
<p id="day"></p>
<p id="month"></p>
<p id="year"></p>
<p id="date"></p>
<p id="time"></p>
<p id="dateTime"></p>
```

Can someone please tell why my setInterval is not kicking in ?

I expect my data to refresh every second.

Comment: It's running every second but the values are not recalculated every second. So on each tick it just re-uses the same values as before.

Comment: move the variables that you are getting outside the function to inside function

Comment: ah got it, It make senses, you guys are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the var for date is defined outside of the interval so it doesn't update. to fix this you'll have to include it in your dateTimeClock function

```
function dateTimeClock() {

var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay()
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear()
var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
  $('#today').text(today);
  $('#day').text(day);
  $('#month').text(month);
  $('#year').text(year);
  $('#date').text(date);
  $('#time').text(time);
  $('#dateTime').text(dateTime);
}

setInterval(dateTimeClock, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your time variables are only called once, so their value doesn't change.

Try calling the time variables from within your `dateTimeClock` function:

```js
function dateTimeClock() {
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDay()
var month = today.getMonth();
var year = today.getFullYear()
var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;


  $('#today').text(today);
  $('#day').text(day);
  $('#month').text(month);
  $('#year').text(year);
  $('#date').text(date);
  $('#time').text(time);
  $('#dateTime').text(dateTime);
}

setInterval(dateTimeClock, 1000);
```